# Show that the Fourier Transform of a function is not in $L^{1}(R)+L^{2}(R).$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Consider the function 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x),$$
where $\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}$ is the indicator function that is equal to $1$ on the set $[0,1]$ and $0$ otherwise. We want to show that $\hat{f}\not\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R})+L^{2}(\mathbb{R}).$

**My Attempt:** First we compute the Fourier transform 
$$\hat{f}(\zeta) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i\zeta x} f(x)dx = \int_{[0,1]} \frac{e^{-i\zeta x}}{\sqrt{x}}dx = 2\int_{[0,1]} e^{-i\zeta t^2}dt.$$
Now if by contradiction suppose there exists $f_1\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f_2\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such that,
$$\hat{f} = f_1 + f_2.$$ 
Then I am not sure how to use this to derive a contradiction. We know that $||f_1||_{L^1}<\infty$ and $||f_2||_{L_2}<\infty$ but then how do we use this information to solve the problem? Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $\hat{f} \in L^1(\mathbb{R})+L^2(\mathbb{R})$, then we can write $\hat{f}=g+h$ with $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $h\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. This gives $f=\check{g}+ \check{h} \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})+L^2(\mathbb{R})$. As $f$ has support in $[0,1]$, we can write 
$$f= 1_{[0,1]} \check{g} + 1_{[0,1]} \check{h}.$$
This implies $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ (as $L^\infty([0,1])\subset L^2(\mathbb{R})$), which gives the desired contradiction.

Comment: How did you get from $\hat{f} = g+h \in L^1+L^2$ to $f=\check{g}+ \check{h} \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})+L^2(\mathbb{R})?$

Comment: Because the inverse fourier transform maps $L^2$ to $L^2$ and $L^1$ to $L^\infty$ (exactly as the fourier transform does). The first is Parseval's theorem and the other is the Fourier-Lebesgues-lemma.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there any reference that you could suggest, I don't know where to read more about this?

Comment: About what in particular?

Comment: Fourier transforms in Lp spaces.

Comment: Honestly I don't know a good reference. If you are interested in integrability you might want to check out the Hausdorff-Young-inequality. It says that for $$ f\in L^p \Rightarrow \hat{f}\in L^q$$ where $1\leq p \leq 2$ and $q$ is the Hölder conjugate of $p$. For $p>2$ things get nasty.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your time!

Comment: Maybe you can ask it as another question. There are many people on this site that are experts in fourier analysis and could suggest a reference that suits your level. Anyway, it was a fun question :)